# Drag external events in Vue FullCalendar SFC

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, fullcalendar

I'm trying to make an option to drag calendar events from an external list to my fullcalendar based on [this codepen](https://codepen.io/BrockReece/pen/LOPwyK?editors=0010) work in my vue/laravel SFC. I got the external events to be draggable but I can't drop them in the the calendar. What should I be doing different here?

I don't get any console errors, plus I'm loading jQuery with webpack so there shouldn't be any multiple instance of JQuery.

My code:
Home.vue

```
<template>
    <div class="home">
        <div class="calendar_wrap">
            <full-calendar :config="config" :events="agenda_items"  @event-selected="eventClick"/>
        </div>

        <div class="sidebar">

            <div class="sidebar__header">
                <button @click="collapse" class="close" aria-label="Close menu" type="button">
                    <svg width="20" height="20" viewBox="0 0 20 20" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                        <path d="M6.66666 4L13.3333 10.6667L6.66666 17.3333" stroke="#B3ECFF" stroke-width="2" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                    </svg>
                </button>

                <h2>Taken</h2>

                <div class="right">
                    <button class="info">
                        <svg width="15" height="15" viewBox="0 0 15 15" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <circle cx="7.5" cy="7.5" r="7.5" fill="#B3ECFF"/>
                            <path d="M7.50839 12.072C7.24439 12.072 7.02439 12 6.84839 11.856C6.68039 11.712 6.59639 11.5 6.59639 11.22V6.84C6.59639 6.56 6.68439 6.348 6.86039 6.204C7.03639 6.06 7.25239 5.988 7.50839 5.988C7.76439 5.988 7.97639 6.06 8.14439 6.204C8.32039 6.348 8.40839 6.56 8.40839 6.84V11.22C8.40839 11.5 8.32039 11.712 8.14439 11.856C7.97639 12 7.76439 12.072 7.50839 12.072ZM7.50839 5.028C7.18839 5.028 6.93639 4.948 6.75239 4.788C6.56839 4.62 6.47639 4.396 6.47639 4.116C6.47639 3.836 6.56839 3.616 6.75239 3.456C6.93639 3.296 7.18839 3.216 7.50839 3.216C7.82039 3.216 8.06839 3.3 8.25239 3.468C8.44439 3.628 8.54039 3.844 8.54039 4.116C8.54039 4.396 8.44839 4.62 8.26439 4.788C8.08039 4.948 7.82839 5.028 7.50839 5.028Z" fill="white"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>

                    <button class="refresh" @click="refresh">
                        <svg width="18" height="14" viewBox="0 0 18 14" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="M3.46343 5.65018C2.92992 7.61243 3.43178 9.79171 4.97355 11.3335C7.14754 13.5075 10.6035 13.6156 12.9011 11.6579" stroke="#B3ECFF" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                            <path d="M5.43711 7.31577L3.46046 4.94736L1.48975 7.31577" stroke="#B3ECFF" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                            <path d="M14.4363 8.39914C14.9698 6.43688 14.4679 4.25761 12.9262 2.71584C10.6384 0.428053 6.93091 0.428053 4.64764 2.71584" stroke="#B3ECFF" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                            <path d="M12.5424 7.3158L14.519 9.68421L16.4897 7.3158" stroke="#B3ECFF" stroke-width="1.5" stroke-miterlimit="10" stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round"/>
                        </svg>
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="sidebar__content">
                <h2>Taken</h2>
                <p>In dit venster vind je het huiswerk dat de docent heeft ingevoerd. Zet de taken op volgorde en plan ze in.</p>

                <router-link class="button primary expanded" to="/newitem">Nieuw agenda item</router-link>

                <div id="external_events">

                    <div class="fc-event">
                        <div class="type">HW</div>
                        <div class="class">Engels</div>
                        <div class="date"> 
                            <span class="date__day">3</span>
                            <span class="date__month">mei</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fc-event">
                        <div class="type">HW</div>
                        <div class="class">Aardrijkskunde</div>
                        <div class="date"> 
                            <span class="date__day">5</span>
                            <span class="date__month">mei</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="fc-event">
                        <div class="type">HW</div>
                        <div class="class">Engels</div>
                        <div class="date"> 
                            <span class="date__day">3</span>
                            <span class="date__month">mei</span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { FullCalendar } from 'vue-full-calendar'
import 'fullcalendar/dist/locale/nl'
import navHeader from '../components/navHeader.vue'
// import mSidebar from '../components/mSidebar.vue'
import Swal from 'sweetalert2'

export default {
    components: {
        FullCalendar,
        navHeader,
        // 'sidebar': mSidebar,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            agenda_items: [],
            config: {
                locale: 'nl',
                minTime: "06:00:00",
                maxTime: "22:00:00",
                editable: true,
                dropabble: true,
                dragRevertDuration: 0,
                nowIndicator: true,
                height: 'parent',
                allDaySlot: false,
                header: {
                    left: 'menu title',
                    center: '',
                    right: 'prev next today month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
                },
                customButtons: {
                    menu: {
                        text: ' ',
                        click: function() {
                            $( ".off-canvas" ).toggleClass("active");
                            $( "#main" ).toggleClass("active");
                        }
                    }
                },
                views: {
                    week: {
                        columnHeaderFormat: "dddd D",
                    },
                    month: {
                        columnHeaderFormat: "dddd",
                    }
                },
                eventRender(event, element) {
                    element.find('.fc-content').append('<i class="delete fas fa-trash-alt"></i> <span class="description">' + event.description + '</span>');

                    element.find(".delete").click(function() {
                        Swal.fire({
                            title: 'Weet je het zeker?',
                            text: "Je staat op het punt dit item te verwijderen",
                            type: 'warning',
                            showCancelButton: true,
                            confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
                            cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
                            confirmButtonText: 'Ja, verwijderen'
                            }).then((result) => {
                                if (result.value) {
                                    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);

                                    axios.delete('/agenda_items/'+ event.id)

                                    Swal.fire(
                                    'Verwijderd!',
                                    'De afspraak is verwijderd.',
                                    'success'
                                    )
                                }
                            })
                    });
                },
                drop() {
                    // remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                },
                eventDragStop: function( event, jsEvent, ui, view ) {

                    var isEventOverDiv = function(x, y) {

                        var external_events = $( '#external_events' );
                        var offset = external_events.offset();
                        offset.right = external_events.width() + offset.left;
                        offset.bottom = external_events.height() + offset.top;

                        // Compare
                        if (x >= offset.left
                            && y >= offset.top
                            && x <= offset.right
                            && y <= offset .bottom) { return true; }
                        return false;
                    }

                    if(isEventOverDiv(jsEvent.clientX, jsEvent.clientY)) {
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', event._id);
                        var el = $( "<div class='fc-event'>" ).appendTo( '#external_events_listing' ).text( event.title );
                        el.draggable({
                            zIndex: 999,
                            revert: true, 
                            revertDuration: 0 
                        });
                        el.data('event', { title: event.title, id :event.id, stick: true });
                    }
                },
            },
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.get_agenda_items();
        this.makeDraggable();
    },
    methods: {
        get_agenda_items() {
            window.axios.get('/agenda_items').then(({ data }) => {
                // console.log(data);

                this.agenda_items = data;
            });
        },
        refresh() {

            this.get_agenda_items();

            $('.refresh').toggleClass("rotate");

        },
        makeDraggable() {
            // initialize the external events

            $('#external_events').sortable()

            var elements = $('#external_events .fc-event')

            elements.each(function() {

                // store data so the calendar knows to render an event upon drop
                $(this).data('event', {
                    title: $.trim($(this).text()), // use the element's text as the event title
                    stick: true // maintain when user navigates (see docs on the renderEvent method)
                });

                // make the event draggable using jQuery UI
                // $(this).draggable({
                //     zIndex: 999,
                //     revert: true,      // will cause the event to go back to its
                //     revertDuration: 0  //  original position after the drag
                // });

            });
        },
        eventClick(item) {
            var data = item.id
            this.$router.push({ path: '/agendaitem/' + data });
        }
    },
  }
</script>
```

app.js

```
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

import jquery from 'jquery'
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/draggable';
import 'jquery-ui/ui/widgets/sortable';
import 'foundation-sites/dist/js/foundation'
require('./bootstrap');
import 'es6-promise/auto'
import axios from 'axios'
import Vue from 'vue'
import VueAuth from '@websanova/vue-auth'
import VueAxios from 'vue-axios'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
import Index from './Index'
import auth from './auth'
import router from './routes'


// Set Vue globally
window.Vue = Vue

// Create eventbus
Vue.prototype.$eventBus = new Vue()

// Set Vue router
Vue.router = router
Vue.use(VueRouter)

// Set Vue authentication
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios)
axios.defaults.baseURL = `${process.env.MIX_APP_URL}/api`
Vue.use(VueAuth, auth)

// Load Index
Vue.component('index', Index)

window.$ = window.jQuery = jquery

/**
 * The following block of code will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

const files = require.context('./', true, /\.vue$/i)
files.keys().map(key => Vue.component(key.split('/').pop().split('.')[0], files(key).default))

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance and attach it to
 * the page. Then, you may begin adding components to this application
 * or customize the JavaScript scaffolding to fit your unique needs.
 */

const app = new Vue({
    router,
    el: '#app'
  });
```